# Should default constructors pass NULLs to another constructor to create dependencies?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor, dependencies

I have a bunch of classes that have a set of dependencies. Dependency Injection for this project will be overkill, so currently we have the following pattern in a number of cases:

```
public MyClass() : this(null, null) {}

public MyClass(Dependancy x, Dependancy y)
{
  this.x = x ?? new Dependancy();
  this.y = y ?? new Dependancy();
}
```

I don't like this code, but I'm not totally sure why. One reason would be the fact that it fiddles with parameters that are passed in, the other is that I might *want* the parameter to be null, and stay null.

Are there any strong reasons to avoid/use this pattern or any other, or is it basically just personal preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing with the code you've posted is that you *are* using dependency injection, you're just *not* using Inversion of Control. `MyClass` has its dependencies injected into it, but it then assumes control of what to do if they aren't as it expects. There's a few reasons this is unpleasant:

1. The higher-level class `MyClass` is coupled to the lower level class `Dependency`.
2. `MyClass` is acting as a [ServiceLocator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx), which in itself is an anti-pattern, but also violates the Single Responsibility Principle.
3. The parameterless constructor has hidden side-effects; the places where it's used are unknowingly constructing `MyClass` with its dependencies both set to `Dependency`.

As @Alessandro Santini says, I'd really encourage you to scrap this and use a DI / IoC container. At the very least get rid of the parameterless constructor and force anything which wants to construct a `MyClass` instance to supply it with appropriate dependencies. The two-argument constructor should then throw exceptions if the dependencies it's given are null.

Comment: Good, was what I was hoping everyone would say! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You do not like it because of two reasons:

- There is no need to have a parametrized constructor to which you pass NULLs; have a second no-args constructor;
- Having a third class (name it Factory, name it Container, does not matter) injecting those default dependencies will never be overkill, compared to the benefits.

Comment: +1 DI is **never** overkill. Maybe you don't have the need for a container, but the pattern itself is **always** a better choice than newing up dependencies in the dark.